# Как в Activity Android Studio добавить API Яндекс.Расписаний?

Tags: android, android-studio, яндекс-расписания

Мне нужно в Activity Android Studio добавить API Яндекс.Расписаний. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ключ я уже получил!

Answer (score 2):

Если к API не предоставлено SDK, то:

1. Берите либу типа `Retrofit`, опишите с её помощью нужные вам запросы.
2. Разберитесь, как получать токен. Скорее всего нужен будет WebView/ChromeTab.
3. В итоге у вас будет и токен и Java методы для вызова методов API с токеном.
4. Методы будут возвращать JSON скорее всего. Его парсите либами типа `Gson`/`Moshi` - получите Java объекты с данными.